# Should we check the shape of arrays before whole array operations in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran

I would like to ask a general question regarding matrix multiplication error handling in Fortran.

Suppose the following code,

```
MODULE MatMulTest
  IMPLICIT NONE
  CONTAINS
      SUBROUTINE C_EQ_AB( A, B, C )
          REAL, DIMENSION( :, : ), INTENT( IN ) :: A, B
          REAL, DIMENSION( :, : ), INTENT( OUT ) :: C

          C = MATMUL( A, B )

      END SUBROUTINE C_EQ_AB
END MODULE MatMulTest

PROGRAM MAIN
  USE MatMulTest
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL, DIMENSION( 3, 2 ) :: B, C
  REAL, DIMENSION( 2, 2 ) :: A

  CALL C_EQ_AB( A, B, C )

END PROGRAM MAIN
```

Now the main program is conceptually WRONG as we are multiplying a (2,2) array with (3,2) array. The error produced by the program is

```
Fortran runtime error: dimension of array B incorrect in MATMUL intrinsic

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x10b5696a9
#1  0x10b56a365
#2  0x10b56a63a
#3  0x10b5f2bab
#4  0x10b563d27
#5  0x10b563e7d
#6  0x10b563eb6
```

From this error message we cannot find (Or Can We?) where the error has occurred(suppose there are many subroutines which performs matrix multiplication.) So should we alway perform a check on the bound or shape of the array? If yes then what is the effect on computational speed given there are many subroutine which performs matrix multiplication? Is there any efficient way to handle matrix-multiplication error?

Comment: Is this really to do with `MATMUL` or pretty much the same issue as with any function that requires consistent arguments? If your algorithm might lead to errors you need to put in a check and live with the performance hit.

Comment: What debugging flags do you use to compile the program?

Comment: It looks like you are using gfortran. Compile with the flags `-g -fbacktrace` if you want to get  line information.

Comment: I was actually trying this now and I don't get the line either (using `-g -fbacktarce`). I can get more info about the matrix dimensions using `-fcheck=all`

Comment: Looks as if it is version dependent. I get a nice trace with `4.4.7` but none for `4.8.4`.

Comment: @RussF Some of the error checks actually suppress backtraces, you only get the line number and file. I remember the pain of having to find out from where it was actually called. Definitely happens for I/O errors.

Answer (score 1):

The information you get depends on your compiler, different compilers will get you different diagnostics.

In gfortran you will get the information about which dimension is non-conforming and what is the shape on the left and on the right.

To find out where did it happen, you got the backtrace. However you only got some addresses and you don't know where do they point. You have to compile the code with a compiler option like `-g`. Consult the manual of your compiler. Then you will get file names and line numbers and not addresses in memory.

---

Should you always check the array shapes? Usually not. Usually you set you code so that such non-conformance can't happen by checks somewhere earlier in the program and by correct program design. If it does happen due to a bug you go to find  and fix the bug. You can place thoce checks temporarilly to find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

For production code probably not...

But! I routinely have D-lines and use the compiler switch -fixed to have development code which can be recompiled without the D-lines.

Sometimes it is worthwhile to have the checking, so I would suggest you just try it to see how you like it.